Concrete reasons to study derived categories of quasi-coherent sheaves on algebraic stacks?
Title says it all. There seems to be a lot of work done on derived categories of quasi-coherent sheaves on stacks, and yet I couldn't find many "external" applications. I'm mainly wondering if there are instances where knowing something about the derived category of a moduli stack says something interesting about the moduli problem?

Among others: the McKay correspondence, moduli of alpha-twisted sheaves with applications to Brauer groups, and the geometric Langlands correspondence . . .

An analogous question might be, why study function spaces on Riemannian manifolds (a major part of harmonic analysis), does it say something about the differential geometry of the underlying manifold? of course the answer is yes  it does (eg hearing shapes of drums) but that's far from the sole motivation.

Typically algebraic stacks are quotients by actions of groups, in which case studying their categories of sheaves is part of representation theory of these groups, broadly construed.

It seems I have approached this from a suboptimal angle. Thank you both!
